# `fs.stat` function for symlink pointing to directory in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, appveyor

In my windows environment (x64), `fs.stat` function for `symlink` pointing to directory brings an error.

On the other hand, in appveyor (ia32), `fs.stat` function for `symlink` pointing to directory works well.

This is why? and which behavior is correct?

A part of my test code is

```
it('Test 001 : fs.stat for symlink', function () {
  var target = path.resolve(workDir, 'sample1');
  console.log('target :' + target);
  fs.mkdirSync(target);                 // create directory
  var link = path.resolve(workDir, 'link1');
  console.log('link :' + link);
  fs.symlinkSync(target, link);         // create symlink to directory

  expect(function() {
    var stat = fs.statSync(link);       // checking symlink stat
    console.log(stat);
  }).not.toThrow();

});
```

Please see https://github.com/knight9999/WindowsSymbolicLinkCheck for all codes.

The result in my local environment is

```
Failures:
1) win symlink tests Test 001 : fs.stat for symlink
  Message:
    Expected function not to throw, but it threw Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\Users\knaito\AppData\Local\Temp\appveyor-tests-winSymlinkTests-VcfaRo\link1'.
  Stack:
    Error: Expected function not to throw, but it threw Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\Users\knaito\AppData\Local\Temp\appveyor-tests-winSymlinkTests-VcfaRo\link1'.
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\Users\knaito\Documents\work\cordova-develop\WindowsSymbolicLinkCheck\spec\winSymlink.spec.js:24:12)
        at <Jasmine>

1 spec, 1 failure
```

The result in appveyor is

```
Started
target :C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\appveyor-tests-winSymlinkTests-NsaPyJ\sample1
link :C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\appveyor-tests-winSymlinkTests-NsaPyJ\link1
Stats {
  dev: 3567992900,
  mode: 16822,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 0,
  gid: 0,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: undefined,
  ino: 844424934502125,
  size: 0,
  blocks: undefined,
  atimeMs: 1537164694047.7703,
  mtimeMs: 1537164694047.7703,
  ctimeMs: 1537164694047.7703,
  birthtimeMs: 1537164694047.7703,
  atime: 2018-09-17T06:11:34.048Z,
  mtime: 2018-09-17T06:11:34.048Z,
  ctime: 2018-09-17T06:11:34.048Z,
  birthtime: 2018-09-17T06:11:34.048Z }
.
```

Please see https://ci.appveyor.com/project/knight9999/windowssymboliclinkcheck .

Note:
I know that the `symlinkd` or `junction` is appropriate for directory in windows.
However `fs.copy` for a `junction` pointing to directory creates new `symlink`  (neither `symlinkd` nor `junction`) automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this issue in detail by myself.

For Windows 10, `fs.statSync` calls nodejs internal function

```
INLINE static void fs__stat_impl(uv_fs_t* req, int do_lstat) {
  HANDLE handle;
  DWORD flags;

  flags = FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS;
  if (do_lstat) {
    flags |= FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT;
  }

  handle = CreateFileW(req->file.pathw,
                       FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
                       FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       flags,
                       NULL);
  if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    SET_REQ_WIN32_ERROR(req, GetLastError());
    return;
  }
  ...
```

in `deps/uv/src/win/fs.c`.
See https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9b292272ff3d71a0ebabe46d040346dbd34585db/deps/uv/src/win/fs.c#L1252 .

`CreateFileW` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` for a `symlink` pointing to other directory.

But for Windows Server 2012 R2 (same as in appveyor), this function works well.

Therefore

```
node -e "console.log(fs.statSync('/path/to/symlink/pointing/other/directory`));"
```

brings error for Windows 10, works well for Windows Server 2012 R2.

I conclude we should avoid `symlink` which points to other directory in Windows 10. A `junction` is better.

Answer (score 0):

If the execution file is inside the folder for ex : src/webpack/ then move the file to src/ and then execute the command in scripts in package.json, it will work.